# windowContentOverlay "no resource found that matches the given name"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to create an app theme with a completely transparent appcompat action bar. I'm trying to remove the shadow below the action bar using windowContentOverlay, however for whatever reason I cannot build using this attribute. The elevation attribute only works for lollipop+ devices and my minimum API level is 16.

What is the issue here?

Error:(12, 29) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowContentOverlay'.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

</style>

<!-- Transparent Action Bar Style -->
<style name="TransparentActionBar"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: it turns out that the windowContentOverlay only works with the android prefix:

<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>

Trying to also define it without the prefix results in the resource not found error (this error points to the one with the prefix for whatever reason). I honestly don't understand why this occurs. I can only assume appcompat doesn't support the windowContentOverlay attribute.

Comment: Cool. I guess its just how the support lib works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Copied Drew's answer from the comments section.

It turns out that the windowContentOverlay only works with the android prefix: `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null<item/>`.

Trying to also define it without the prefix results in the resource not found error (this error points to the one with the prefix for whatever reason).

I honestly don't understand why this occurs. I can only assume appcompat doesn't support the windowContentOverlay attribute.